# set CORS for AWS Presign URL and set cacheControl for S3 files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I'm new on AWS and I have 2 questions:

1. I use Presign URL to generate URL for video, it works fine. But when I put video URL to other website, it shows normally. I want it serve on my domain only. I set CORS config like this but it doesn't support Presign URL, it works for images and other types only.

[image]

bucket settings like this
[image: bucket settings]

2. I transfer files from other website to S3, I need to set cache control meta for each file. I have code like below but it doesn't work. Is there any way to set a rule that apply to all uploaded files to S3, it will update meta automatically?

   // transfer videos to S3
   export const transferVideoToS3 = (videoUrl, filename, callback) => {
   request({
   url: videoUrl,
   encoding: null
   }, function (err, res, body) {
   if (err) return callback(err, res);

   ```
        s3.upload({
            Bucket: 'myvideos',
            Key: `public/videos/${filename}.mp4`,
            cacheControl: 'max-age=604800',
            ContentType: res.headers['content-type'],
            ContentLength: res.headers['content-length'],
            Body: body // buffer
        }, callback)
    })
   ```

   }

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be achieved by the following settings

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, path)
.withMethod(HttpMethod.PUT).withExpiration(expiration);

generatePresignedUrlRequest.addRequestParameter("cache-control","max-age=604800,public");
```